# Selected attribute depending on params value with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, parameters

I have an action that renders a view which contains this:

```
<select id ='dynamic_select'>
  <option value = "<%= activity_path %>">All</option>
  <option value = "<%= activity_path(:type => 'enrolled') %>">Enrolled</option>
  <option value = "<%= activity_path(:type => 'redeem') %>">Redeem</option>
  <option value = "<%= activity_path(:type => 'social') %>">Social</option>
</select>
```

What would be the correct/Rails way of rendering that select and mark as selected one of the options depending on the type parameter:
If there is **no type** parameter, select "All" options, if there is **type=enrolled** parameter select Enrolled option, and so on...

I have managed to do that client side with Javascript, but I am wondering what would be the Rails way of doing so.

Rendered HTML:

```
<select id="dynamic_select" name="dynamic_select">
<option value="/activity">All</option>
<option value="/activity?type=enrolled">Enrolled</option>
<option value="/activity?type=redeem">Redeem</option>
<option value="/activity?type=social">Social</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following.  I have displayed the select_options here, but you should probably generate them in your controller and pass them through to the view.

The key is using [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select).

```
<% select_options = {"All" => activity_path} %>
<% %w{Enrolled Redeem Social}.each {|opt| select_options[opt] = activity_path(:type => opt.downcase)} %>
<% form_for(resource) do |f| %>
  <%= s.select :dynamic, options_for_select(select_option, :selected => select_options[@default || "All"]) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this is populating the select with the options correctly, but is not adding the "selected" attribute depending on the type parameter...Notice that I don't submit a form, I use onChange with JS, but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: See my edits.  I think the second argument is a hash, and the selected key determines which one to use.

Comment: What is the @default? And, the selected won't work for 'All' because the value is a full URL and not a single string...

Comment: @default should be the string of the one you want selected by default. ("Enrolled", etc.)

Comment: Yes, but how and where do I set that? That's basically the problem I am dealing with. How to dynamically select one option by using the type parameter. Notice that even if I hardcode the value to "Enrolled" it doesn't work, because the value of the option is a path: notice -> select_options[opt] = activity_path - I have added the rendered HTML in my question...

Comment: Oh, I see.  Set it to `select_options["Enrolled"]` then to look it up from your hash.  The default should be set in your controller, I guess it is coming from the database or something?

Comment: Gazier: This did the trick: :selected => activity_path(:type => params[:type]) - If you want to add it to your answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  As an aside, you should assign params[:type] somewhere in your controller btw.  You shouldn't be accessing params in the view.